# How to handle android:imeOptions="actionNext","actionDone" in fragments in ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to handle "actionNext" and "actionDone" to do something in fragments in ActionBarActivity,but it can't work.
When I call setActionListeners () I got an error,but i don't know how to resolve it.

My code:

```
public void setActionListeners() {
    fir_ET.setOnEditorActionListener((OnEditorActionListener) this);
    sec_ET.setOnEditorActionListener((OnEditorActionListener) this);
}

public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {  
    switch(actionId){          
    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "next:" + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break; 
    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:  
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "done:" + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;  
    }         
    return true;  
}
```

logcat:

```
09-04 12:12:49.150: E/Trace(1778): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.rtev_t3_2.WriteData cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView$OnEditorActionListener
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.rtev_t3_2.WriteData.setActionListeners(WriteData.java:132)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.rtev_t3_2.WriteData.initView(WriteData.java:76)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.rtev_t3_2.WriteData.onCreateView(WriteData.java:61)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-04 12:14:58.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: Maybe I should say it more clearly . I'm new to android. so I just know there is something wrong ,but i don't know what it is.
When I debug and called setActionListeners() it jump ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run ()

Comment: If your app is indeed crashing, you should be able to use logcat to obtain a complete stacktrace from the crash. If you are using Eclipse or Android Studio, logcat is baked in to the IDE. Otherwise, you can see instructions for using it via the command line here at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, and then tell me if there is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logcat it looks like you haven't actually implemented the `OnEditorActionListener` interface. Simply adding a `onEditorAction()` method doesn't make your class an `OnEditorActionListener`; you still need to implement the interface.

Your class should look something like this:

```
public class MyClass implements OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

This also eliminates the need to cast your class to `OnEditorActionListener`, so instead of

```
fir_ET.setOnEditorActionListener((OnEditorActionListener) this);
```

You can simply call

```
fir_ET.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
```

Comment: So if my class doesn't implement OnEditorActionListener, I will have to New OnEditorActionListener () and override onEditorAction () method, when I "setOnEditorActionListener", right?

Answer (score 0):

Your class WriteData must implement OnEditorActionListener to set listener in this way

```
fir_ET.setOnEditorActionListener((OnEditorActionListener) this);
sec_ET.setOnEditorActionListener((OnEditorActionListener) this);
```